# C# Application Store Email/Password Safely / Not Hardcoded

Tags: c#, email, imap

I am currently developing a c# application in which I have to send an e-mail to some kind of request-storage. I found several ways to send mails in c# code and every one of them requires mail and password (Which makes totally sense). **But** I don't want to hardcode the mail or / and the password in my application. I think that would be the worst thing you could do in this situation.

Does anyone have an idea how it would be possible to store the e-mail and password safely and easy accessable **without any webservice**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your application is targeted at external users (i.e. not a service running on your own internal company server) and that your main concern about hardcoding the credentials is with having to update all instances of your application when the credentials change? I'd ask you in a comment but I don't have the reputation yet.

You could store the credentials in encrypted form somewhere, e.g. a database and then decrypt them in-memory (you can just search for this, there are many example implementations available).

Of course, someone could disassemble your application and discover your method of decryption and gain access to the credentials, so depending on whether you see this as a risk, you could consider protecting your code from disassembly using some third-party software.

It can never be completely protected as long as your code runs on the users machine, but it would increase the effort required to obtain the credentials substantially, compared to storing the credentials somewhere in plain text.

However, I'm not clear why you'd want to avoid using a webservice? That would be a nice way of separating the concern of sending emails from your application code. 
You could then completely change the implementation, without the client application having to worry about it.

Comment: Do you know a - for this case - good, free and easy accessable webservice? I do not need plenty of tools and functions..

Comment: I have only ever implemented my own, but e.g. 
https://www.mailgun.com/ looks promising
Here's a list of APIs: http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-10-email-apis/

Comment: mailgun.com looks good but don't I need a domain to send mails?

Comment: Yes you do, and you could still go with your own implementation instead if that's easiest for you  - either way works. My original suggestion was that you wrapped your implementation of sending email in a web service, which would allow you to change the implementation without having to force users to update their client applications. Using a service such as mailgun is a convenience which you could consider, but if you have your own mail-server already and you need to send a lot of emails, perhaps it's not worth it.

Comment: Another note: you'd still need to maintain the credentials/certificate to send mail through a mail service in each client application, so it doesn't make that part easier. That was your main question, so perhaps I've strayed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your password in webconfig/AppConfig file as below so you can access easily.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="UserName" value="*******" />
 <add key="Password" value="*******" />
</appSettings>
```

you can access these fields as below you may required to add a reference of
    System.Configuration;

```
string userName= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string password= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

Comment: I think it is fine otherwise we can use some encrypt technologies to store in appconfig and we have to write code to retrieve this by decrypt this value after read from config.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm guessing you're creating a console/desktop app?
An option might be to store the username/password in the appSettings in the app.config, which can be encrypted. See [Jon Galloway's](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file) options to go about that.